# PC not starting with ram installed - it is stuck in a turn-on, turn-off loop

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

-CPU installed

-NO sticks of memory (RAM)

-NO hard disks / storage devices

-NO peripheral cards on (PCI-E/PCI/AGP/etc)

Literally just CPU and motherboard connected to the PSU

Turns on, runs fine/continously, gives error code of "No RAM detected"

-CPU installed

-1 stick of memory (RAM) installed

Starts this off/on boogie dance and keeps cutting out, off. When I put ram in, it powers on for 2 seconds, cuts off, 3 seconds pass, it powers on again, and shuts off.

The ram matches the requirements for the MOBO, and works (tested in other pc, one that I'm using right now)

I tried every slot of ram, tried different cards of ram and nothing works.

When ram is inserted, it powers on for 2 seconds, fans spin, and then it cuts off. 3 seconds later, it powers on for 2 seconds, fan spin and then cuts off. PSU has a solid green light, and I haven't tested with a spare PSU but when ram isn't installed, it runs quietly and great

OptiPlex 9010, 3.3ghz Intel CPU

Had 2 ram sticks (matching), out of operating station. Tried 1,3 and 2,4 slots, no ram sticks were identified by any of the slots in any configuration.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Was it working before you installed the RAM?

Comment: @KevinBillings If you're the one down-voting everyone's answer, I hope its not because it doesn't SOLVE your eact issue. People are helping you for FREE so any advice is advice you didn't have before. I'd upvote answers that you believed were helpful & ultimately YOU mark one as the ANSWER when you deem it fit. People loose reputation scores when you down-vote so people won't want to help you if you're unwilling to take advice

Comment: Just seeing this, but no I wasn't downvoting, that's pretty immature. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain exactly WHAT happens when the RAM is inserted? Try a power discharge: remove power cord & power on, then reconnect & try again. Look at motherboard (or see a manual) to try & use jumpers to reset CMOS. If PSU has button, did you hold that & confirm solid green LED to test PSU or a spare PSU? Did you look for bloated capacitors? Agreed what you're seeing is abnormal, but you seem to know that too. Maybe the rest of the POST is drawing more power or hitting other failing parts of motherboard that aren't tested/used when RAM is disconnected.

Comment: When ram is inserted, it powers on for 2 seconds, fans spin, and then it cuts off. 3 seconds later, it powers on for 2 seconds, fan spin and then cuts off.  PSU has a solid green light, and I haven't tested with a spare PSU but when ram isn't installed, it runs quietly and great.

Comment: @KevinBillings if the PSU green light was when you pushed black button on back of PSU then it passed its built-in test & I suggest you edit your question to show those details. Did you do the power discharge, clear CMOS with jumpers, or see bulged capacitors? Please edit your question with those details.

Comment: Green button on PSU just means its on, not that its a test, my mobo doesn't have a green light that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Some manufacturer got limited set of RAM that work inside their motherboard. In example in a HP I have only some kingston's one that are comptabitle or the oem's one. Tried other and I get the same symptom as you.

Make sure your RAM is listed compatible for your model.

Your case look similar, as even the [lookup](https://www.kingston.com/en/memory/search?model=78321&deviceType=2&mfr=DEL&line=Optiplex) tool, or that [one](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Dell/optiplex-9010-%28mini-tower%29) find me only some matching your model.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to face a similar problem with you. But I don't know if the solution can be solved for your problem. I try to take the RAM out and clean the connector between RAM and motherboard. Sometimes, RAM cannot be read by the motherboard. Try clean your RAM. Maybe it can solve your problem. Hope this help.